# How to deploy a WebJob from a pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

I'm attempting to deploy a WebJob for an App Service, alongside the app service itself. But no method I've found has worked. All of the online info on the topic seem to be out of date (with no Microsoft documentation that I can find).

Everything else works- I've verified that the artifact has all the correct files, in the correct places. The app service itself gets uploaded fine. The issue is purely the WebJob. (I've edited this for clarity and security)

```
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  BuildConfiguration: 'Release'
  AzureSubscription: 'Subscription'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'select'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '**/API.csproj'
        configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/APIOutput'
        platform: 'any cpu'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '**/WebJob.csproj'
        configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/WebJobOutput'
        platform: 'any cpu'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - job: DeployJob
    steps:
    - download: current
      artifact: 'drop'

    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      inputs:
        ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
        azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
        appType: 'webApp'
        WebAppName: 'WebAppName'
        packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/APIOutput'

    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      inputs:
        ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
        azureSubscription: '$(AzureSubscription)'
        appType: 'webApp'
        WebAppName: 'WebAppName'
        packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/WebJobOutput'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have referred this [blog](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-webapp-with-webjobs-dotnet-core-build-depoy/) by Rahul Nath and Deployed **Azure Web App + Azure WebJob** together using **Azure DevOps Build and Release pipeline**  and also **Deployed it in a single Build YAML Pipeline**

Refer my [Github Repository](https://github.com/sid24desai/WebJobwithWebApp1), Referenced from [Rahul Nath's repository](https://rahulpnath.visualstudio.com/YouTube%20Samples/_git/WebAppWithWebJobs?ref=rahulpnath.com) with my own Azure YAML Pipeline to deploy the Web App + WebJob in a single yaml pipeline.

I Pushed this repository in Azure DevOps repos and then built my Azure Web app + Azure WebJob solution like below:-

**My Build YAML pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/WebJobExample.WebJob.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/YoutubeWebJob'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Now, Use **build Artifact in your release pipeline**.

Select your build artifact above in the Release pipeline:-

[image]

In the Stage select Deploy Azure App Service task and add the required configurations :-

I created one **.Net 6.0 Windows Azure Web app** and selected it in my Task like below:-

[image]

In Deploy Azure App Service step added **`**/appsettings.json`** in the File Transform step and kept rest of the settings as it is:-

[image]

Added one variable with **AzureWebJobStorage** **connection string** which is the **connection string of my Storage account:**-

[image]

Now, I saved the pipeline and created a Release:-

Release was successful and Azure Web App + Azure Web Job got deployed successfully:-

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to **run this in a single YAML pipeline** refer the **code below**:-

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/WebJobExample.WebJob.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/YoutubeWebJob'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'


- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'xx subscription (xxxxxxxxxxxe97cb2a7)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'valleywebappjob'
    packageForLinux: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    WebConfigParameters: '**/appsettings.json'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Putting the WebJob in the app data folder as specified did indeed cause the WebJob to show up in the list. Thanks a lot for that. I've been spinning my wheels for a while trying to get this to work.